# Improve "What topics can I ask about here?"

Tags: discussion, help-pages

Just by chance I've read askubuntu's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) site and found some good ideas there.
Can we also improve our [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

They've a "Information needed when creating a question" part:

> - Apply as many tags as makes sense. We get a lot of traffic so it's in your best interest to spend a few minutes making your question show
>     up the right section.
> - If a question involves any hardware issues, provide relevant information (Eg: If your question is about a graphics issue, provide
>     video card type, video drivers and anything related to it)
> - Questions should show as much information about your problem as possible. The more work and time you put on your question, the easier,
>     faster and better the answers will be.
> - Make sure the Question's title shows what the problem is about. Asking "Ubuntu has problem" is not the same as "Unity not loading
>     after installing Ati drivers". Be specific about it.
> - Remember that we can only help you using the information you have provided on the question. If your question lacks information, a
>     solution will take more time to arrive.

Many of these would be useful on our site too.

Comment: Tell me again why you didn't stand for the moderator post?

Comment: @Burgi thanks for your confidence! Besides not having enough time to really act as a moderator; I don't feel I'd have experience comparable to current moderators'.

Comment: Nice idea, but I can't then use my "I am neither psychic nor a mind reader and I don't like guessing games.  What is ..." comment :)

Comment: More seriously, answers containing suggestions for the additional text can be considered and voted upon.

Comment: I tend to be in the "less is more" camp when it comes to tag. I'm also pretty certain we have the stock/standard one there.

Comment: Nice, but this belongs on another help page - [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7):

Well, this is an exercise in futility, because [users don’t read](https://blog.codinghorror.com/teaching-users-to-read). 
But, as an exercise, here’s a collection of some of my pet peeves:

- Questions should include any essential information about your problem –
  it helps others work out solutions to your problem.<sup>1</sup>

  - If you want help with something that failed, describe *how* it failed. 
    If you got an error message, *quote* the error message in your question.
  - If you want help with a processing problem
    (e.g., spreadsheet or text manipulation),
    describe *and* give examples of your input, what processing you want to occur,
    and what output you want to get. 
    Describe what you have tried and what results you have gotten.
  - [Please don’t post images of text](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408). 
    If at all possible, post a textual representation of your data,
    as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988);
    use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) site if you want. 
    (Of course if your question concerns charts and graphs,
    or fonts and/or colors,
    it may be necessary to post images *to supplement your textual description*.)
  - Identify what operating system(s) you are using,
    and provide version numbers of all relevant software.
- The question title should be the *title*. 
  The title is not the first sentence of the question. 
  The body of the question should make sense
  even if the reader ignores the title (and the tags).
- As much as possible, your question body should be written
  in the form of complete, correct English sentences. 
  Ideally, one of them should be an actual question
  (i.e., it should have a “?” at the end). 
  Do not just describe your situation
  and assume that we’ll guess what you want to do about it. 
  Avoid asking multiple questions in one question post.

Some of the above may need to be de-snarked a little. 
Also, not all of these
fall under the “Information needed when creating a question” heading.
____________
<sup>1</sup> This is obviously copied directly
from [Journeyman Geek’s answer](//meta.superuser.com/q/12283/150988#12290).

Comment: Nice, but this belongs on another help page - [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: True. Feel free to tell the [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) people that they got it wrong.  :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 3):

I like most of these, not all. I do think some wording changes may be nice.

- Apply appropriate tags as needed. This helps users who may specialize in that tag find them.
- If a question involves any hardware issues, provide relevant information (Eg: If your question is about a graphics issue, provide video card type, video drivers and anything related to it)
- Questions should include any essential information about your problem - it helps others work out solutions to your problem
- Question titles should be descriptive - They are the first thing people see and being specific helps find them.

I'd personally leave the last one out.

Comment: Nice, but this belongs on another help page - [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)